# Can one override keyboard shortcuts in Sketchup through the a Ruby Plugin or Console?

Tags: sketchup

I would like to develop a Sketchup Script that adds some specific keyboard shortcuts.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SketchUp API currently doesn't expose access to change the keyboard shortcuts. As things are now the best thing you can do is document how your users can hook up new shortcuts to the menus or toolbar buttons you add.